# How to debug function values

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to understan what is wrong in function? but cant find what is wrong

```
Sub test()
Dim a as double, b as double
    a = "10,31" 
    b = "10,31"
Msgbox check(a,b)
End Sub

Function check(a as double, b as double)
    ff = TypeName(a) ' double
    gg = TypeName(b) ' double
    If a= b Then GoodExVat = True Else GoodExVat = False: diffExVAt = b - a ' here a = 10,31 b=10,31 diffExVAt = -3.5527136788005-15
check = diffExVAt 
End Function
```

if a and b seted as  10,31 everything is ok, but when 10,31 comes from other function or expression then i got `-3.5527136788005-15`

What is that? It is not first time i got same thing. What is wrong with Excel?

Comment: `a as double` and `a = "10,31"`???

Comment: yes as value comes from string

Comment: `"10,31"` will be stored as `1031` which is not what you want :)

Comment: it stored and i see in debug what it = 10.31

Comment: Also what is the objective of `GoodExVat`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Depends on locale settings.

Comment: `?Application.DecimalSeparator` gives you `,`?

Comment: yes Application.DecimalSeparator gives `,`

Comment: BTW, on my computer, even with Decimal Separator to `.` I got `?cdbl("10,31")` returning `10.31`, probably because I don't have `,` as thousand separator and have `,` as currency decimal separator (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `:` in `It`-`Else`, it is a bit confusing. If you write it normally, it should work ok:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim a As Double, b As Double
    a = "10,31"
    b = "10,31"
    MsgBox check(a, b)
End Sub

Function check(a As Double, b As Double)
    ff = TypeName(a)    ' double
    gg = TypeName(b)    ' double
    If a = b Then
        GoodExVat = True
    Else
        GoodExVat = False
    End If

    diffExVAt = b - a    ' here a = 10,31 b=10,31 diffExVAt = -3.5527136788005-15
    check = diffExVAt

End Function
```

And concerning debugging - simply use <kbd>F8</kbd> and the Step-by-step method.

---

Concerning the `10,31` coming from other function and expression and getting a `-3.55...-15`, then the problem is in the floating point mathematics:

- [Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)
- [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: So how to get `-3.5527136788005-15` making 10,31-10,31 ?

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - there are plenty of answers, depending on the accuracy you need. The easiest one is `If Abs(a - b) < 0.01 Then check = True` or simply round the values up to the second digit.

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - Can you give an example of the "comes from other function or expression"? Most probably they are not rounded to the second digit, but you think they are... Read the two links in my answer, they are pretty interesting.

Comment: how to see full value digits count in debuger?

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - select the the variable and press Shift + F9. Or simply write `?NameOfValue` in the immediate window.

Comment: ++ for following it to the end :)

Comment: But debuger do not show full digits (( only help Round both values

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - the `?NameOfValue` in the Immediate window should show all the digits. E.g., write `?a` to see the digits of `a`.

Comment: No showing only 2 digits `10,31` as is. but when i do `round(a,2)` when `GoodExVat  = True ` instead of `False` without Round

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - try with Shift + F9.

Comment: result the same

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - this is strange. However, the `-3.55...-15` is coming for sure from the double arithmetics. Simply you are missing one of the variables somewhere and it is "poisoning" the whole system. Try writing `debug.print a` for every variable, thus printing them and see  their values.